# amp-ad srcdoc or srcdoc equivalent

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I would like to use amp-ad's in a preview environment. The constraint of the preview environment is that we are not allowed to serve ads via a request.

A common use case for creative ad tech developers is to use iframes and their srcdoc attribute to render ads and debug them.

As a result, I try'd to get a amp-ad rendering via a srcdoc but didn't have any luck. Is it possible to use the srcdoc attribute or insert html into a amp-ad frame without making requests to an external or internal source.

The way AMP allows for 3rd party content to render in amp-ads is through the amp-3p-custom-ad meta tag.

Comment: Are you talking about using AMP for Ads or the amp-ad tag?

Comment: @SebastianBenz The amp-ad tag.

Comment: @SebastianBenz https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6829 I found this. It might be close to what I need.

Essentially if that feature is implemented I will be able to create a `amp-iframe` with a `srcdoc` and inside use a script to inject the `window.context` api

Comment: It's best then to continue the discussion on the GH issue.